# Build project has encountered a problemm Eclipse C++.

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, build, binaries

Details are saying I have two different tools of the same compiler. I'm not sure where to go from here to fix this so I can build my project. Any ideas?

This is the detailed message:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project '263_Hw'.
Internal error building project 263_Hw configuration Debug
Generated resource conflict: 
two resources of the same name: /263_Hw/Debug/main.o 
generated by different tools 
tool1: GCC C++ Compiler 
tool2: GCC C++ Compiler

Generated resource conflict: 
two resources of the same name: /263_Hw/Debug/main.o 
generated by different tools 
tool1: GCC C++ Compiler 
tool2: GCC C++ Compiler

Internal error building project 263_Hw configuration Debug
Generated resource conflict: 
two resources of the same name: /263_Hw/Debug/main.o 
generated by different tools 
tool1: GCC C++ Compiler 
tool2: GCC C++ Compiler

Generated resource conflict: 
two resources of the same name: /263_Hw/Debug/main.o 
generated by different tools 
tool1: GCC C++ Compiler 
tool2: GCC C++ Compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely situation: you have two source files with the same name but different file extensions. In your case, that would likely indicate you have something like

main.c
main.cpp

in your project tree. Could be tricky to see, especially if you have a lot of nested folders. I'd go to your source root and do a search for main.*

Comment: That's what my problem was.  Same file name with c and cc extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In Ecplise, right Click on project -> Properties -> C\C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor. In the 'Current Builder' select box, select 'Gnu make builder' -> Apply (or Ok).
Try building the project again.

If you've exhausted all other options try using the gcc make tool directly:

1) Open the command line

2) cd to the folder containing the Make files (i.e. # cd 'C:\Path\To\MakeFile')

3) Assuming you have a typical MINGW windows install, run the command # C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe all

4) the above command can be shorter if you have the MinGW folder set as a path variable.

5) The output binaries should be found in the bin folder in the same location.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: It made the error go away, but now I only get 'nothing to be done for all'

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same problem before but i don't remember what i did about it! For starters one way to try to solve it is by checking if you have more than one MinGW folder installed on your computer (I am assuming you use MinGW)! Also Check your project properties->c/c++ General->Paths and symbols->Includes and making sure that there are links to only one minGW folder! (It may look something like this (except for you they may start with "c:/mingw/...":[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the project (not the source code, just remove the project from Eclipse) and recreate it from scratch and setting up the include paths and linker paths again. Then it compiled properly.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I deleted a project from the workspace.  I reimported the project with the same name to the same workspace, and when I tried to rebuild I got this error.

What I did was to delete the project from the workspace again, and then check my local directory where the workspace folder is.  Voila, the deleted project is still in the workspace folder.  So I deleted that project folder, then reimported the project again.  It worked for me this way ;)